# Prove that one eight of Gauss circle problem counts integer sided acute triangles with largest side n.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

In the OEIS there is the [sequence A247588](https://oeis.org/A247588)
starting: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 21, 25, 27,...
It has the name "Number of integer sided acute triangles with largest side n."

Let $a(n)$ be that sequence prepended with a zero.
$a(n)$ = 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 21, 25, 27,...
Calculate:
$$(n + n^2 - 2*a(n))/2 = 1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 32, 40, 49, 57, 66,...$$
where: $$n=1,2,3,4,5,...$$

> Prove or disprove that $(n + n^2 - 2*a(n))/2$ is equal to one eight of [Gauss circle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html).

One eight of Gauss circle problem is computed as follows:
$$\sum _{n=0}^r \left(\sum _{k=0}^r \text{If}\left[k^2+n^2\leq r^2,\text{If}[n\geq k,1,0],0\right]\right)=1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 32, 40, 49, 57, 66,...$$
where:

$$r=0,1,2,3,4,...$$

Mathematica:

```
a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 21, 25, 27, 31, 34, 39, 43, 
   48, 52, 56, 63, 67, 73, 80, 84, 90, 96, 104, 111, 117, 126, 132, 
   140, 147, 154, 165, 172, 183, 189, 198, 210, 219, 229, 237, 247, 
   260, 270, 282, 292, 302};
a1 = Table[(n + n^2 - 2*a[[n]])/2, {n, 1, 32}]
nn = 32 - 1
a2 = Table[
  Sum[Sum[If[n^2 + k^2 <= r^2, If[n >= k, 1, 0], 0], {k, 0, r}], {n, 
    0, r}], {r, 0, nn}]
a1 - a2
```